# Cross-compiling for Windows .NET ARM64 using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, arm, cross-platform

I am trying to build a .NET class library written in C++, targeting the ARM64 platform under Windows.

The code builds fine for x86 and x64 platforms. It does compile for the ARM64 configuration, but linking fails by not finding MSCOREE.lib. [Non .NET code compiles and links.]

I thought to have understood that the .NET framework only supports ARM64 as of version 4.8.1. I installed the .NET SDK 4.8.1 and recompiled for Framework v4.8.1 to no avail. The framework itself cannot be installed because my machine is x64, but this is unimportant for now.

Maybe do I need to adjust the paths to the libraries in Visual Studio (2022), but I can't find the files of that .NET SDK.

Can anyone help me perform a successful build ?